# vb xor checksum

Tags: vb.net, checksum, xor

This question may already have been asked but nothing on SO actually gave me the answer I need.

I am trying to reverse engineer someone else's vb.NET code and I am stuck with what a `Xor` is doing here. Here is 1 line of the body of a soap request that gets parsed (some values have been obscured so the checksum may not work in this case):

```
<HD>CHANGEDTHIS01,W-A,0,7753.2018E,1122.6674N, 0.00,1,CID_V_01*3B</HD>
```

and this is the snippet of vb code that checks it

```
LastStar = strValues(CheckLoop).IndexOf("*")
StrLen = strValues(CheckLoop).Length
TransCheckSum = Val("&h" + strValues(CheckLoop).Substring(LastStar + 1, (StrLen - (LastStar + 1))))

CheckSum = 0
For CheckString = 0 To LastStar - 1
    CheckSum = CheckSum Xor Asc(strValues(CheckLoop)(CheckString))
Next '

If CheckSum <> TransCheckSum Then
    'error with the checksum
    ...
```

OK, I get it up to the `For` loop. I just need an explanation of what the Xor is doing and how that is used for the checksum.

Thanks.

PS: As a bonus, if anyone can provide a c# translation I would be most grateful.

Comment: Evidently, the checksum is computed by XOR-ing all the characters together.  I'm not sure there's much more to say about it than that...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth so is it just that simple, the Xor is a method of providing an indicator that the string is intact? I suppose I am not seeing the benefit of this here - what logic am I proving/confirming?

Comment: A checksum is really any function that reduces an arbitrary-length string down to a small fixed-length string.  Some checksum functions have better properties than others.  A simple XOR checksum is pretty crude (it doesn't identify swapped bytes, for example), but it's very easy to calculate.  And if any one byte in your data is corrupted, it's guaranteed to tell you about it (it won't tell you *which* byte, of course).

Comment: Is this a NMEA sentence with the checksum being the character after the * ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Xor` is a simple algorithm to calculate a checksum. The idea is the same as when calculating a [parity bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_bit), but there is eight bits calculated across the bytes. More advanced algorithms like CRC and MD5 are often used to calculate checksums for more demanding applications.

The C# code would look like this:

```
string value = strValues[checkLoop];

int lastStar = value.IndexOf("*");
int transCheckSum = Convert.ToByte(value.Substring(lastStar + 1, 2), 16);

int checkSum = 0;
for (int checkString = 4; checkString < lastStar; checkString++) {
  checkSum ^= (int)value[checkString];
}

if (checkSum != transCheckSum) {
  // error with the checksum
}
```

I made some adjustments to the code to accomodate the transformation to C#, and some things that makes sense. I declared the variables used, and used camel case rather than Pascal case for local variables. I use a local variable for the string, instead of getting it from the collection each time.

The VB `Val` method stops parsing when it finds a character that it doesn't recognise, so to use the framework methods I assumed that the length of the checksum is two characters, so that it can parse the string `"3B"` rather than `"3B</HD>"`.

The loop starts at the fourth character, to skip the first `"<HD>"`, which should logically not be part of the data that the checksum should be calculated for.

In C# you don't need the `Asc` function to get the character code, you can just cast the `char` to an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

The code is basically getting the character values and doing a Xor in order to check the integrity, you have a very nice explanation of the operation in this page, in the Parity Check section : http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/xor.html